# How to pass a list of widgets into a listview efficiently in flutter?

Tags: performance, flutter, listview, dart

The method getCandidates() returns a list of widgets which I am passing into a list view as shown below. There are only 3 candidates and the app is performing very poorly when I check my dartDevTools memory snapshot any suggestions on how I can improve performance?

```
List<Widget> getCandidates() {
  List<Widget> recentCandidates = [];
  List<Candidate> candidates = candidateList();
  for (Candidate candidate in candidates) {
    recentCandidates.add(CandidateCard(candidate: candidate));
  }
  return recentCandidates;
}
```

**THE LISTVIEW**

```
  Container(
              height: 200,
              child: ListView(
                addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: getCandidates(),
              
              ),
      
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

It is NOT efficient to build a `ListView` on a seperate method.
What you can do is create a method that can build one `Widget` and then call it recursively.

[You can also refer to this YouTube Video which I have found useful.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwk0jPRwb-s)

For your reference, put this inside your `build` method:
(You can remove the `Row` and replace it with a `Widget` like a `Column` or a `ListView`.)

```dart
Container(
  child: Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: List<Widget>.generate(items.length,
    (index) => makeItem(items[index], index))),
  ),
),
```

And then call a `makeItem` method and customize it with your reference:

```dart
Widget makeItem(Map widget, int index) {
  if (index == _selectedIndex) {
    return YourIndexBasedWidget()
  } else {
    return OtherWidget();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a "most efficient way" to pass a list of widgets but ways that take more or less lines of code. Here is how I like to do it in a few lines only :

```dart
List<Candidate> candidates = candidateList();

Container(
   height: 200,
   child: ListView(
      addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
         ...candidates.map<Widget>((Candidate e) => CandidateCard(candidate: e)).toList(),
      ],
   ),
)
```

By doing so you keep your code small and (in my opinion) still easy to understand. You don't need to use a temporary variable like you have done using `recentCandidates` and you don't event need to create a dedicated method.